# How to compare specific cell values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```
If cells(3,11).value="c:users\flap-fis.txt"
```

This condition is getting failed every time either we have file location of or not.

How can I write the code how to check specific cell value with static string?

Comment: `celles` should be `cells`. Also specify in which worksheet this cell is eg. `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 11)`

Comment: Oops typo mistake ..but it is same cells still not working

Comment: "Not working" is no error description. Did you specify a worksheet for `Cells`? Note that your path is missing a backslash ` \\` right after `c:` it should be `"c:\users\flap-fis.txt"`

Comment: Voted to close as "Needs Detail or Clarity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how to debug VBA projects? Best thing to do for such a case is putting a breakpoint on that particular line and use the "immediate" window, where you can ask `? <var>` in order to know the value of a variable, as in these examples:

```
? Cells(3, 11).Value = "c:users\flap-fis.txt"
False

? Cells(3, 11).Value
c:\users\flap-fis.txt
=> Mind the extra backslash, as already mentioned by PEH.
```